# How to set a link to a button depending on the desition taken?

Tags: javascript, html, css

All i want is that if the user decide to have a multiple set value, then the "next" button get a different link to a different page .

```
  var singleMulticontainer = document.getElementById("singleMultiContainer");
    var singleMultiValue =  singleMultiContainer.options[singleMultiContainer.selectedIndex].value;
    var nextButton = document.getElementById("nextButton");
    var multipleSetWindow = "window.location='multiSet.html'"

    if(singleMultiValue == "multi"){
        nextButton.onclick = multipleSetWindow;
    }
    else{
        alert("notworking");
    }
```

The HTML fragment:

```
<form id"suspendedProperties">
    <p><h4>Select Station:
    <select name="stationDropdown">
        <option value="50028000">Tanama</option>
        <option value="60008001">Example Riv1</option>
        <option value="60008002">Example Riv2</option>
        <option value="60008003">Example Riv3</option>
        <option value="60008004">Example Riv4</option>
     </select>
     </h4></p>

    <p>Select Sample Medium:
        <select name="sampleMediumDropdown">
          <option value="Wer">Wer</option>
          <option value="WSQ">WSQ</option>
        </select>
        </p>
    <p>Begin Date
        <input type="date"/>
     </p>
     <p>Hydrologic Event: <select name="hydroEvent">
                            <option value="1">Example 1</option>
                            <option value="2">Example 2</option>
                            <option value="3">Example 3</option>
                            <option value="4">Example 4</option>
                            <option value="5">Example 5</option>
                            <option value="6">Example 6</option>
                          </select>
</p>
<p>Add:<input type="number" size=""/> <select name="singleMultiContainer"><option value="single">Single container sample</option><option value="multi">Multiple sets container</option></select></p>
 <p>Analyses Requested:(Applies to all samples)<br/></p>
 <div id="analyses" >
 <input type="checkbox" name="analysis" value="C">Concentration</input> 
 <input type="checkbox" name="analysis" value="SF">Sand-fine break**</input>&nbsp;  
 <input type="checkbox" name="analysis" value="SA">Sand analysis**</input>  <br/>
 <input type="checkbox" name="analysis" value="T">Turbidity</input> 
 <input type="checkbox" name="analysis" value="LOI">Loss-on-ignition**</input>&nbsp;    
 <input type="checkbox" name="analysis" value="DS">Dissolve solids</input>  <br/>
 <input type="checkbox" name="analysis" value="SC">Specific conductance</input>                                     
 <input type="checkbox" name="analysis" value="Z">Full-size fractions**</input>
 </div>
<input type="button" value="Back" onClick="window.location='SED_WE.html'"/>
<input type="button" value="Next" onClick="window.location='SampleInfo.html'"/>
</form>
```

So the last 2 lines are the next and the back buttons. I want to give the next Button the multiSet.html value if the user choose to have multiple sets container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to show us your HTML for us to advise exactly.

If it's an actual link, then you can programmatically set the `.href` property which determines what URL the link is set for.

If it's a button that has code attached to it, then you can set a property that the click handler uses to determine what URL to go to.

For example, if it's the button with click handler, you could have this normal code:

```
// default value for nextURL in your initialization code
var nextURL = "singleSet.html";  

// click handler for the button
function handleClick() {
    window.location = nextURL;
}
```

Then when you want to change the value, you just change the value of that variable

```
// change the value
nextURL = "multiSet.html";
```

You could also avoid using a global variable and use an attribute on the button itself, but I kept the above example as simple as possible.

---

```
<input id="nextButton" type="button" value="Next" onClick="window.location='SampleInfo.html'"/>
```

Add, an id to the button and then you can change its click handler to a different function like this:

```
document.getElementById("nextButton").onclick = function() {
    window.location = 'multiSet.html';
};
```

---

A better way to do this is to put the destination for the button as an attribute on the button:

```
<input id="nextButton" data-location="SampleInfo.html" type="button" 
    value="Next" onClick="window.location=this.getAttribute('data-location');"/>
```

And, then to change the destination for the button, you just change the attribute value on the button:

```
document.getElementById("nextButton").setAttribute("data-location", "multiSet.html");
```

Comment: Thank you for a fast response, I made changes so you can see the HTML.

Comment: @Ch32k0 - I added two more options to the end of my answer for your particular HTML.

Comment: Thank you, but the page keeps redirecting me to the same page, the thing is that I'm new to this and I think I might have not link the script well, but as soon I resolve the issue I let you know. Thank you again

Comment: Thank you, the problem was that I didn't put the id  :S...simple enough, haha.. THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR ANSWER!!

Comment: And sorry for asking to much, I want to get the value of the dropdown and compare it to a string, how do i get the value ?

Comment: @Ch32k0 - give the select an id like `id="qty"` and you can get use `document.getElementById("qty").value` to get the selected value as a string in the select control.

Comment: It's automatically sending me to next page ...in this case  multiSet.html

Comment: @Ch32k0 - I have no idea what your last comment means.  Here's a simple working example that fetches the value from the select control: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/vjAyy/

Comment: it worked the only change it needed was to put singleMulti value inside the funtion for whent it refreshed it gets that value